# How to change NLTK default wordnet language to zsm?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm new to NLTK and I'm doing the Python 3 Text Processing with NLTK 3 Cookbook: Chapter 4. I've done "Using WordNet for tagging" and works fine in default language English. I've download Language Bahasa (zsm) to omw and want to try in Bahasa using other datasets. Using the same approach, how can I change the language default from English to zsm now?

Code that I'm using:

```
class WordNetTagger(SequentialBackoffTagger):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SequentialBackoffTagger.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.wordnet_tag_map = {
            'n': 'NN',
            's': 'JJ',
            'a': 'JJ',
            'r': 'RB',
            'v': 'VB'
        }

    def choose_tag(self, tokens, index, history):
        word = tokens[index]
        fd = FreqDist()

        for synset in wordnet.synsets(word):
            fd[synset.pos()] += 1

        if not fd: return None
        return self.wordnet_tag_map.get(fd.max())
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you seem to have figured out, you don't change the *default* language; you explicitly specify the language you want, whenever you don't want the default. If you find this onerous, you could wrap the `wordnet` object in your own custom class that provides its own defaults.

```
class MyWordNet:
    def __init__(self, wn):
        self._wordnet = wn

    def synsets(self, word, pos=None, lang="zsm"):
        return self._wordnet.synsets(word, pos=pos, lang=lang)

    # and similarly for any other methods you need
```

Then you initialize a wrapper object, passing it the nltk's `wordnet` reader object, and later you use this instead of the original:

```
wn = MyWordNet(wordnet)
...

for synset it wn.synsets(word):
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you @alexis for your help. It works and I was looking for, but the result were different from mine. Most of the words tagged None using your suggestion. It's like escaping many words compared to explicitly specified like mine. Urmm, interesting. Any idea how this happen.

Comment: Well... my answer showed how to override a default argument with a wrapper class, but not how to _actually_ do it with wordnet! Oops... Checked and fixed now, take another look. (The main thing was matching the signature of the original `synsets()` method.)

Comment: Thanks again @alexis for your feedback. I've tried it and still return the same. However we'll leave it to others to test both approach using their dataset later. As for now your suggestion answered my main question :-) ps: mine was using [link](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html)

Comment: I tested this solution and it works correctly. Since I don't know what you're actually doing with it, I can't speak to your remaining problem. (Btw I'm not sure what you mean by the link to the howto in your comment.)

Answer (score 0):

After some trial I just figured:

```
def choose_tag(self, tokens, index, history):
    word = tokens[index]
    fd = FreqDist()

    for synset in wordnet.synsets(word, lang='zsm'):
        fd[synset.pos()] += 1

    if not fd: return None
    return self.wordnet_tag_map.get(fd.max())
```

Key is wordnet.synsets(word, lang='zsm') works now for me. And I'm still open for any other suggestion or correction. Thanks.