# Find a word's class (POS tag) in Greek using python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, pos-tagger

I'm currently working on a document classification app. I use python along with NLTK and wordnet for English which enables me to find a word's class. My problem is that I currently haven't found a way to do the same thing in other languages such as Greek.

I found the Greek Wordnet in http://wordnet.okfn.gr/downloads/. 
I saved the folder within NLTK corpora folder and tried to load it with:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet-master
```

but I got an SyntaxError

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I change the name to wordnet_master, I get an ImportError

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'wordnet_master'
```

Is there any suggestion on how to import the Greek Wordnet? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the content of `wordnet-master` file. For obvious reasons I am not going to download it and open it :P, but if it is python module (which I doubt because of hyphen `-` in actaul name), you need to have `__init__.py` in the folder you kept it in order to import it

Comment: Unfortunately, as you suggest it's not a python module. It contains some txt files, like index.txt which has the following: ENG20-00208807-v wngre:synset-βρέχω-verb-0
ENG20-00208847-n wngre:synset-ανθρωποκτονία-noun-0
ENG20-00209353-n wngre:synset-ανθρωποκτονία-noun-0
ENG20-00209719-v wngre:synset-κατακλύζω-verb-0
ENG20-00210487-v wngre:synset-υγραίνω-verb-0
ENG20-00210861-v wngre:synset-ξηραίνομαι-verb-0

Comment: Have you checked if the Greek WordNet is provided in the existing WordNet corpus included in NLTK using the command `sorted(wn.langs())`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I checked the wn.langs() command and it returned [u'eng', ...u'ell',..]. So it seems that Greek WordNet corpus is included. Even though, when I try commands like wn.synsets('το', lang='ell') I get [ ]. So I suppose something is not working. I don't know if the problem lies in the corpus or I'm not doing something right.

Comment: I tried several words to test the corpus but I got the same result. For example I tried the word 'ενοχλώ' which can be found in the corpus (/nltk_data/corpora/omw/ell/wn-data-ell.tab). Again, wn.synsets('ενοχλώ', lang='ell') returns [ ]. The tab file contains "... 00063291-v      ell:lemma       ενοχλώ"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wordnet interface to NLTK uses english by default. When making a call to `synsets()`, an additional `lang` argument can be used to specify the language you are interested in. When used with the available languages in `wn.lang()` it seems to work appropriately.

Here are a few examples in greek, spanish and italian.

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('ενοχλώ', lang='ell')
[Synset('irritate.v.02'), Synset('harass.v.01'), Synset('tease.v.01')]
>>> wn.synsets('molestar', lang='spa')
[Synset('interrupt.v.02'), Synset('tease.v.02'), Synset('disturb.v.01'), Synset('faze.v.01'), Synset('annoy.v.01'), Synset('tease.v.01'), Synset('chafe.v.01'), Synset('trouble.v.02')]
>>> wn.synsets('annoiare', lang='ita')
[Synset('tire.v.02'), Synset('tire.v.01'), Synset('bore.v.01')]
```

[a previous similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569307/how-to-change-nltk-default-wordnet-language-to-zsm), uses a wrapper class to enforce a default language, which may be good for your use.

Comment: Nathan, thank you for your answer. As you can see in the comments of my original post I have already tried  'wn.synsets('ενοχλώ', lang='ell')'   but the result was negative. In the meantime I tried several other languages with success. I tend to believe that the problem lies on encoding (even though I use utf8), because the only languages failing are the ones with non-english charactes. e.g. tha, ell

Comment: P.S. Nathan, the problem in my case was caused by Python version. I used Python 2 so i had to use the u prefix to get it working. Now, as Alexis suggested I switched to Python 3 and everything is working properly! Thanks again

Comment: sorry wasn't able to respond until now, glad it got resolved. didn't think about encoding issues. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. 
Finally I found a workaround. Greek language is supported (out-of-the-box) by WordNet via omw corpus. It seemed like it was not working, but after reading [Greek encoding in PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519004/greek-encoding-in-python), I used the u prefix and the problem was solved!

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

wn.synsets(u'ενοχλώ', lang='ell')
```

resulted to

```
[Synset('irritate.v.02'), Synset('harass.v.01'), Synset('tease.v.01')]
```

Please note the u before the word in question (in this case 'ενοχλώ').

The same with Thai

```
wn.synsets(u'หายใจ', lang='tha')
```

gave

```
[Synset('breathe.v.01'), Synset('respire.v.02')]
```

Comment: Here's a very important suggestion: Switch to Python 3 today. There's no reason to drive yourself crazy trying to deal with the Python 2 text model, when you're just getting started on this. In this case, your synset code would have worked out of the box. Enough reason?

Comment: Also: If you want POS tags, you need a POS tagger, not wordnet. Google around for a POS tagger for Greek, or try your luck with this one: http://php-nlp-tools.com/posts/pos-tag-application.html (in PHP, but you can run it as an external process).

Comment: Alexis, thank you very much for your suggestion. I switched to Python 3 and now looking to the link you sent me. I' m also looking for a way to lemmatize Greek words, but I think It wouldn't be right to discuss it under this post, since the original question is a little bit irrelevant. Anyhow, any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Don't have any ideas for lemmatization, you'll have to google and work it out yourself. Questions that ask for a software recommendation are off-topic for this site, but if you do find a lemmatizer you can ask for help if you have trouble getting it to work properly.

Comment: PS. Please "accept" either Nathan's answer (would be my choice) or your own, to mark your question as resolved. You should also edit your answer to mention that the reason you couldn't get Nathan's answer to work was because you were using Python 2.